# WooCommerce additional email on completed order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I have a question, which need a community support as I couldn't find anything on the web including WooCommerce support forum.

I have a WooCommerce site which is a closed e-commerce store used by local chain of restaurants. Each time stores order anything, GM would also like a email sent to him on completed order, so he can either block the order or approve it. GM1 is responsible for Store1, Store2 and Store3; GM2 is responsible for Store4, Store5, and Store 6 and so forth.

With the help of internet, this is what I have so far in function.php. Function is working properly and getting triggered, but all 3 GMs are getting email, but in theory, only one GM should get email. GM1 for Store1 OR Store2 OR Store3; and GM2 should get email if Store4 OR Store5 OR Store6 orders.

Really appreciate if somebody can point me to the right direction or atleast let me know why all three ifs are getting triggered.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);

function your_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $object) {
    if( 'Store1@store.com' || 'Store2@store.com' || 'Store3@store.com' == $recipient ){
        $recipient = $recipient .= ', GM1@store.com';
    }

    if( 'Store4@store.com' || 'Store5@store.com' || 'Store6@store.com' == $recipient ){
        $recipient = $recipient .= ', GM2@store.com';
    }

    if( 'Store7@store.com' || 'Store8@store.com' || 'Store9@store.com' == $recipient ){
        $recipient = $recipient .= ', GM3@store.com';
    }

    return $recipient;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any vendor plugin along with it ?

Comment: Check the PHP Control Structures documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php), it should be `if` and `elseif`.

Comment: No, not using any vendor plugins.  I also tried if{} elseif{}, but still the same results. All 3 GMs are getting emails.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an array() as below which seems to be working:

```
function your_email_recipient_filter_function( $recipient, $order ) {

$Stores1 = array('Store1@store.com', 'Store2@store.com', 'Store3@store.com');
$Stores2 = array('Store4@store.com', 'Store5@store.com', 'Store6@store.com');
$Stores3 = array('Store7@store.com', 'Store8@store.com', 'Store9@store.com');

$StoreEmail =  $order->billing_email;

if ( in_array( $StoreEmail, $Stores1)) {
    $recipient .= ', GM1@store.com';
} elseif ( in_array( $StoreEmail, $Stores2) ) {
    $recipient .= ', GM2@store.com';
} elseif ( in_array( $StoreEmail, $Stores3) ) {
    $recipient .= ', GM2@store.com';
} 
return $recipient;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order', 'your_email_recipient_filter_function', 10, 2);
```